# what is access_token ,what is purpose of usage or what is it used for?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How's the current state of Facebook's session and access_token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006695/hows-the-current-state-of-facebooks-session-and-access-token)

I am using facebook sdk v3.0 to develop facebook applications. Could you answer following questions for me ;

1) what is access_token ? 
2) Is it required to store ID of access_token in database with user id ? 
3) Has access_token specified life time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ahem.*

- As for #1 ("What is *an* access_token?"), a single search has brought forth http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ (y'know, the ***official documentation*** page for *the platform you're developing for*, hint hint), which says:

> App authentication ensures that the user is giving their information to your app and not someone else. Once these steps are complete, your app is issued an user **access token** that you enables you to access the user's information and take actions on their behalf.

- As for #3 ("Does an access_token have a specified lifetime?") , the very same page says:

> In addition to the access token (the access_token parameter), the response contains the number of seconds until the token expires (the **expires** parameter). Once the token expires, you will need to re-run the steps above to generate a new code and access_token [...]

- As for #2, it follows that an access token is temporary, and thus you don't need to store it permanently.